# Unable to render an Alpha Transparant texture

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, transparency

I am creating rocks with a group-hair particle system of leaves on top of the rocks. The leaves was just an alpha image being textured into a plane. It was working fine.

However, when I render the alpha image, there are shadows of the plane. I wanted it just to have shadows on the leaf and not the alpha-part of the image. What is the cause? 
Here is the [blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/30875).

P.s. I already checked transparency on the material of the plane and make sure to have zero alpha and spectacular. Also, when I render the leaves alone (not the particle system), it appears fine. Like on the pictures below.

[image]
There are shadows when in particle system.
[image]
[image]

Here is the Textures for the leaf (I can't get 3mb to upload here. Btw, the source was from a tutorial by Andrew Price):
http://www.pasteall.org/pic/75151

Comment: you will need to pack the textures, or we won't be able to test propperly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using buffer shadows, which according to [the documentation](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Lighting/Lamps/Spot/Buffered_Shadows) cannot render transparent shadows.

> Raytraced shadows are generally more accurate, with extra capabilities such as transparent shadows, although they are quite slower to render.

Comment: Actually, this isn't quite right. The [manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/lighting/lamps/spot/buffered_shadows.html#irregular) states that transparency works with Irregular Buffer and Deep Buffer. In reality, I've never managed to get it to work (see my question about it [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51395/how-to-get-transparent-shadows-using-a-spot-with-irregular-deep-buffer)).