# How to get transparent shadows using a spot with irregular/deep buffer?

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine, transparency, shadows

I'm using Blender's internal renderer, trying to get some transparent shadow using a spot light with deep or irregular buffer switched on. Contrarily to this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14821/168), the [manual for  2.77](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/lighting/lamps/spot/buffered_shadows.html#irregular) states this about the Irregular Buffer:

> This method **supports transparent shadows**. To do so, you will first
>   need to setup the shadow setting for the object which will receive the
>   transparent shadow.

and this about the Deep Shadow Buffer:

> Deep Shadow buffer **supports transparency** and better filtering, at the
>   cost of more memory usage and processing time

*(That last bit is even in the button's tooltip.)*

**Yet**, when I map this png image onto a plane:

[image: Orange circle with alpha channel]

then switch my light to spot and the shadows to deep/irregular buffer, making sure that the plane underneath is set to receive transparent shadows, I do not get transparent shadows, but this:

[image: render result]

So my question is, is there any extra step needed to get it to work, or is the feature broken, or am I missing something or what?

Comment: Blender internal works in mysterious ways..  select the objects that receive the shadow and enable receive transparency

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I have done that, but still no transparent shadows...